# Combine PySide and PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, pyside

I want to develop an UI containing both forms for the user to configure the app and also a "render" part which will print some sprites for example.

Is it possible to combine PySide and PyGame in the same application? For example, how can i get a PySide Frame containing a Pygame application?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest, most natural solution is probably just to use a [QGraphicsView](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QGraphicsView.html). E.g. for sprites, implement a subclass of QGraphicsItem, and override the paint() function to display the appropriate frame.

If you absolutely insist on using PyGame, you could easily run the PySide and PyGame bits in separate windows. For embedding PyGame *inside* a PySide widget, it's probably going to be much harder, and the PySide widgets won't gel as seamlessly (you can actually stick GUI elements like buttons **inside** a QGraphicsView and transform them!).